# Mysql- Generating Report Output using Data stored in table

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement, where I need to generate a report. The database which I am using is MySql.

I have captured the information in a table, and I am able to export the output to a csv file using

```
             select * into   outfile /dir from <my_table name>
```

which gives the output into a table snapshot separated by tabs.

What I would like to have is:

```
             Project Name
             Start Date
             End Date

       |Tracker Status| |Date1|                          |Date2|             |Date3|  

             New        Count of projects with new status  Count            Count
```

Can this be directly done using mysql query,without using any package of Python etc?

I have posted generic output format.

I know I can do this in Python, but I don't have time for that.

Thanks

**UPDATE** Now, I have an issue related with counts.

Suppose the date created_on = '2016-7-20' has total count 10 for a particular status, such as 'New'.

In the output query, which I have written, the counts are not coming in proper format.

Is there any way to get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL (and most databases) is a data analysis tool not a presentation tool.  If you want a fancy header on your result set then yes you should consider using something like Python or PHP.

Comment: It is not possible in database tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this:

```
      select @projectname,CONCAT(@start_date,'-',@end_date)
      union
      select 'Tracker_Status',REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(date(created_on)) ,'|', date(Date),'|'),',','')
      from finance_dashboard.dashboard_data where status='New' 
      union 
      select 'New', REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Initial_count,'|',count_as_of_date),'|'),',','')
      from finance_dashboard.dashboard_data where status='New'
      union 
      select 'Estimated',REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Initial_count,'|',count_as_of_date),'|'),',','')
      from finance_dashboard.dashboard_data where status='Estimated'
```

This is not complete solution, but I am able to get the result:

```
'Cyrcle Connect', '2016-01-01-2016-11-30'
'Tracker_Status', '2016-07-12|2016-01-05|2016-07-12|2016-07-30|2016-07-12|2016-08-10|2016-07-12|2016-11-14|2016-07-12|2016-01-05|2016-07-12|2016-07-30|2016-07-12|2016-08-10|2016-07-12|2016-11-14|'
'New', '57|3|9|3|9|3|3|2|57|3|9|3|9|3|3|2|'
'Estimated', '3|2|9|2|3|2|3|2|3|2|3|2|3|5|9|5|3|5|3|5|3|5|3|5|3|2|9|2|3|2|3|2|3|2|3|2|1|7|3|7|1|7|1|7|1|7|1|7|3|2|9|2|3|2|3|2|3|2|3|2|3|5|9|5|3|5|3|5|3|5|3|5|3|2|9|2|3|2|3|2|3|2|3|2|1|7|3|7|1|7|1|7|1|7|1|7|'
```